# CSS to span column height to window height?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the left and right column span to the window height and give the user a scrollbar to independently scroll the two columns. How can I do this?

I've been trying `min-height: 100%` and `height: 100%` but it doesn't seem to work no matter where I use it.

I setup a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Legend/t5cUA/1/

**EDIT**: I don't want to add `position: fixed`. I still want the columns to align if the user reduces the width of his browser window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure all the previous wrappers are set to `height: 100%` and `overflow: hidden`. Something like [this fiddle shows](http://jsfiddle.net/t5cUA/8/) (may need some tweaks depending on what exactly you want):

```
html, body, .container-fluid, .container-fluid > .row-fluid {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.span-fixed-sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

### Update from Clarification

You just need to continue the process deeper. The point is that you need to set the scroll on the actual column element(s) you want to scroll, and have everything else explicitly set to the `height: 100%` and `overflow: hidden` that wrap that column. [Probably this for you](http://jsfiddle.net/t5cUA/12/):

```
html, body, .container-fluid, .container-fluid > .row-fluid, .span-fixed-sidebar {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.span-fixed-sidebar > div {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. Actually, I wanted the left and right panes to scroll independently. In your version, they scroll together. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Awesome! Accepted as answer. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're right. I just remembered I did not check that and came back and voila... I see your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

It you want to scroll content of left and right column independently you have to add

```
overflow: auto;
```

to it's CSS. Also, note, that 100% height can be set to children of relative or absolute block, or to children of block with defined height.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand the question but if you want to span to the window height and put a scroll if the column is higher than the window:

```
.column {
  overflow: auto /* scroll */;
  height: 100%;
}
```

EDIT: Yes, `overflow: auto` will be a better option if you don't want to show a scroll if the column is not high enough.