# Left menu with Height and Min-height 100%

Tags: html, css

Thanks for your patience.
I need to make a left menu with height and min-height 100%
For example.

If the website doesn´t have a lot of content, the left menu should go to bottom
If the website has a lot of content, the left menu should go to bottom also, but with scrollbar...

The left and right divs always must be 100%

[Image Example http://www.diegomenezes.com/stack.jpg](http://www.diegomenezes.com/stack.jpg)

It could use HTML5

Here ou can see the JSFiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/6gSYn/

And here my code!

```
    <div id="container">
    <div id="top"><h1>TESTE</h1></div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="left">
        <ul class="lista">
            <li>ITEM 1</li>
            <li>ITEM 1</li>
            <li>ITEM 1</li>                
            <li>ITEM 1</li>
            <li>ITEM 1</li>
            <li>ITEM 1</li>
            <li>ITEM 1</li>
            <li>ITEM 1</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
        <p>TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE </p>        

            <div id="footer">
            <p>TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE TESTE </p>
            </div>
    </div>
    </div>    

</div>
```

Here the CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
background: darkgrey;
height: 100%;

}

#container {    
height: 100%;
position: relative;
}

#top {
height: 100px;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
color: white;
float:left;
}

#content {
background: darkgrey;
width:100%;
min-height: 100%;
height:100%;
}

#content ul.lista {
width: 250px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
background: lightgrey;
color: red;
bottom: 0;
}


#right {
width: 1000px;
color: blue;
display: inline-block;
padding: 10px;
min-height: 400px;
}


#footer {
color: black;
height: 50px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: why min-height 100%?  why not height 100%?

Comment: It could be! But if it has just some content it should go to bottom also... but I tried everything and nothing worked!

Comment: So you want the menu on the bottom? at all time? And why at the bottom? and not top?

Comment: Yes! The menu should go to the end of the page. Starting at the top.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6gSYn/2/ and another one http://jsfiddle.net/6gSYn/3/

Comment: hello @Morpheus thanks for your help, but in this fiddle the menu is not going to the end of the page! =(

Comment: @Diego Menezes take a look at second example

Comment: @Morpheus http://jsfiddle.net/6gSYn/2/ this one?! I can´t find the working version

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6gSYn/4/

Comment: The left menu is not going to the bottom yet... even on the example 3 ... tested on firefox and chrome @morpheus

Comment: @Morpheus I get the impression that the OP wants the menu bar to be the taller of: the height of the page or the height of the content - eg it will always reach the bottom of the scrollable area but won't shrink if content is shorter than that (nor force scroll bars if the content doesn't require them)

Comment: Yes! @Basic just got it!

Comment: @Morpheus I saw the last update you made! But it´s creating scrollbars on X and Y... even with a little content. :(

Comment: The last attempt :) http://jsfiddle.net/6gSYn/8/

Comment: Sorry @Morpheus ... but it didn´t work with a lot of content... the left menu just don´t go to the bottom anymore. =( Thanks for you patience with this issue!

Comment: Possible repeat of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666834/how-to-create-a-gmail-like-layout-with-twitter-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

Try this and tell worked for you or not [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gSYn/7/)
**CSS:**

```
#right {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

td {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @navand that is an approach that I have tried... but it´s not the best one to do... If I can´t find a solution will try this one!

Comment: You don't want to use `<table>`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a pure `css` solution of this problem. There might be some ticks which are not easy to understand and implement. Rather you can solve your problem using little javascript or precisely jQuery.

lets assume the code block as follows-

```
<div id="mainContainer">
    <div id="leftContainer">
        <p>Some contents which you want to put in the left blovk</p>
    </div>
    <div id="rightContainer">
        <p>Some contents which you want to put in the right blovk</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

now to make these two div `leftContainer` and `rightContainer` having same width you need to add some `js`-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// making the height of the right container same as the left one

    leftContainerHeight = $('#leftContainer').outerHeight();
    $('#rightContainer').height(leftContainerHeight);

//or

// making the height of the right container same as the left one

    rightContainerHeight = $('#leftContainer').outerHeight();
    $('#leftContainer').height(rightContainerHeight);

});
```

This `js` will set the height of the container of your interest dynamically. But one fallback is if your dom is really heavy or visitor has a slow connection, then there will occur a height jump. That means you'll see the height of the dependent container will increase sharply as soon as your page completed loading.
To avoid this there you can use a loading gif image or simply a `fadeIn` effect of the contents. You can learn more about the fadeIn effect [here](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn)

Here's the fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/6gSYn/9/

If you need more assistance here please feel free.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order for height:100% to function properly in all browsers your parent element would need to have a height specified to a pixel height. This is complicated as sometimes your content will need more room than the specified height. You could use javascript to get around this problem but that is not always the best solution.